# Rails Elasticsearch error: [400] No handler found for uri [//items] and method [PUT]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I'm trying to implement `elasticsearch` with two models `account.rb` and `item.rb`. The account model contains the address info and the item model contains the searchable item.

I'm also using the `gem geocoded` in order to get the latitude and longitude coordinates when the address is inserted to the `account.rb`.

With the following setup I'm receiving this error:

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest in ShowcaseController#index
[400] No handler found for uri [//items] and method [PUT]
```

on these two lines `item.rb` and `showcase_controller.rb` respectively:

```
Item.__elasticsearch__.client.indices.create \
@items = Item.all
```

item.rb

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :store

  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

  settings index: { number_of_shards: 1, number_of_replicas: 0 } do
    mapping do
      indexes :location, type: 'geo_point'
    end
  end

  def location
    [latitude, longitude]
  end

  def self.search()
    __elasticsearch__.search(
        {
            query: {
                match_all: {}
            },
            sort: [{'_geo_distance' => {
                location: {
                    latitude: 0,
                    longitude: 0
                }
            }
                   }]
        }
    )
  end
end

Item.__elasticsearch__.client.indices.delete index: Item.index_name rescue nil


Item.__elasticsearch__.client.indices.create \
  index: Item.index_name,
  body: { settings: Item.settings.to_hash, mappings:  Item.mappings.to_hash }

Item.import
```

showcase_controller.rb

```
class ShowcaseController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @items = Item.all
  end

  private

  def front_params
    params.require(:front).permit(:title, :description, :price, :image, :location )
  end
end
```

Any ideas on how to solve this error?

Comment: facing the same issue

Comment: Found any solution? I'm facing the same issue!